# find 2 local martingales M(t) and N(t) such that M(T)=N(T),but for t<T,M(t) $\ne$ N(t)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, local-martingales

question:

find 2 local martingales M(t) and N(t) such that M(T)=N(T),but for t < T,M(t) $\ne $ N(t).

I can only find one is local martingale and the other one is martingale.

can you help me think of one example?

Comment: If the "other one" is a martingale, it is, in particular, a local martingale... so where exactly is your problem?

Comment: oh yes，i need the both to be local martingales，but not be martingales